# Heat equation with a source and homogenous boundary and initial conditions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, differential-equations, diffusion, thermal-conductivity

I am trying to solve the following:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-3\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-9$$
$$u(0,t)=0=u(\pi,t)$$
$$u(x,0)=0$$
So solving the homogenous case first by separation of variables $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ to get the eigenvalue. Substituting and dividing by XT we get:
$$\frac{\ddot X}{X}-3\frac{\dot T}{T}=0$$
Therefore by solving the space part and applying BC we get:
$$X_n=sin(nx)\:\lambda_n=n^2$$
Now we have: $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(t)sin(nx)$
and substituting this in our original equation we get and reordering:
$$-n^2T_nsin(nx)-3\dot T_nsin(nx)=-9$$
Expanding -9 into Fourier series we get:
$-9=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nsin(nx)$ with coefficients
$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi -9sin(nx)dx=\frac{-18}{\pi}\int_0^\pi sin(nx)dx=\frac{18}{n\pi}cos(nx)\mid_0^\pi=0$$
Which means we get to solve
$$\dot T_n+n^2T_n=0 \;\;\; T(0)=0$$
Solving this we get: $T_n=c_1e^\frac{-n^2t}{3}$ and applying the IC we get $c_1=0$ but this means $T_n=0 $ for every $n$ so the solution for u is also 0.$$ $$ This answer doesn't make any sense to me. How do we have a source with prescribed tempretures 0 at the boundaries and the whole rod is at 0 in the begining and it stays the same? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Formulating an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method described below works for heat equations with non-homogeneous boundary conditions and heat equations with a heat source (our case here). I can't provide full details because it's a homework question, so I'll only outline methodology.

Using PDE shorthand:

$$u_t=\frac13 u_{xx}+3\tag{1}$$

Now we look for the **steady state** solution, that is for $u_t=0$. I'll call it $u_E(x)$:

$$u_t=0 \Rightarrow \frac13 u_{xx}+3=0$$

$$u_E''(x)=-9$$
$$\Rightarrow u_E(x)=-\frac{9}{2} x^2+c_1x+c_2$$

You need to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$ using the boundary conditions (BCs)(I won't do that here).

Now $u_E$ is a **particular solution** of $(1)$ and satisfying also the BCs.

*There must now exist also another solution*, call it $v(x,t)$, so that with the Superposition Principle:

$$u(x,t)=u_E(x)+v(x,t)$$

Now for a few derivatives:
$$\Rightarrow u_t(x,t)=0+v_t(x,t)$$
$$\Rightarrow u_{xx}(x,t)=-9+v_{xx}(x,t)$$

Inserting into $(1)$, we get:

$$v_t=\frac13 v_{xx}\tag{2}$$

Which is **homogeneous**! Now also transform the $u$-based BCs into $v$-based BCs and you'll find that these are also **homogeneous**, e.g.

$$u(0,t)=u_E(0)+v(0,t)=0\Rightarrow v(0,t)=0$$

So $(3)$ with the 'new' BCs can be solved for $v(x,t)$, **with separation of variables** and the usual Fourier series for coefficient determination.

Note that the initial condition:

$$u(x,0)=0=u_E(x)+v(x,0) \Rightarrow v(x,0)=-u_E(x)$$

The solution is then:

$$\boxed{u(x,t)=-\frac{9}{2} x^2+c_1x+c_2+v(x,t)}$$

From an initially flat $u=0$, a parabolic temperature profile develops over time. As $t \to +\infty$, then $v(x,t) \to 0$, so that:

$$u(x,+\infty)=-\frac{9}{2} x^2+c_1x+c_2$$

Comment: Following your method I get inhomogenous initial condition $v(x,0)=-u_e(x)=9x^2/2+9\pi x/2$ which when I solve for I need to expand in Fourier series in $sin(nx)$. Is this correct or I made mistake when I converted the initial conditions.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But it only makes the determination of the coefficients marginally harder. See e.g. this case: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HeatEqnNonZero.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Once again you help me with my PDEs :D

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you solve an inhomogeneous differential equation, the general solution is $u = u_H + u_p$, where $u_H$ is the general homogeneous solution (which you derived: $u_H=0$ and $u_p$ is a (one) particular solution. Solving for the homogeneous solution alone doesn't really help; as you found out, it is zero for all $x$ and for all $t$.

To find a particular inhomogeneous solution, you can solve the steady-state solution for $u_{xx} = -9$, which is a second-order polynomial in $x$; you can apply boundary conditions and you will find that it is a unique solution; let's call it $u_s(x)$ (for "steady-state").

Then, write your general solution as
$$ u(x, t) = u_s(x) + \sum_n c_n u_n(x, t),$$
where $u_n$ are the general solutions of the homogeneous equation, i.e. $u_n(x,t) = \sin(nx)e^{-n^2t/3}$. If you substitute this in the PDE, you'll find that this is the general solution of the inhomogeneous equation. Now, solve for $c_n$ for an infinite series in $n$.

Note that the general solution is not a Fourier series, because that would apply to the domain $0\leq x < 2\pi$ (and with $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms), whereas you only have $\sin$ terms and cover half the $x$ range.

Comment: But I do have a constant source -9. It still stays to 0 since you can't get under the absolute zero temperature?